# How to achieve Higher and lower compatibility in android

Tags: android, cordova, android-2.2-froyo

Currently I am developing the application with lower version sdk-platform:2.3.3 Revision :2 . and application is running perfectly without any problem .. now i want to make this app forward compatible so that i can run this app on higher version please suggest me how to upgrade my code so that my app can run on all devices ...

Tell me what all changes I have to do in my manifest file below. I am using the Phonegap and cordova to make platform compatible ...

Cordova :1.6.1 -- Suppose if i upgrade my cordova it should work fine ...

I just ran my application on higher version of android my application is getting closed please tell me how to solve this problem

Here is the Logcat file , I am getting network connection error..
If i App in Version 4.0.3 API:15 ... Please check what is the problem and suggest me the best solution so that my app is comparability with higher version.

It crashes as soon as i run the application . Its showing me prompt that network error as occurred

my manifest.xml

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.lbs"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <supports-screens
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:resizeable="true"
            android:anyDensity="true"
            />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

```
12-17 17:25:17.914: D/DroidGap(534): Origin to allow: http://127.0.0.1*
12-17 17:25:17.954: I/CordovaLog(534): Found log level DEBUG
12-17 17:25:17.954: I/CordovaLog(534): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
12-17 17:25:17.974: I/CordovaLog(534): Found preference for classicRender
12-17 17:25:17.974: D/DroidGap(534): DroidGap.onCreate()
12-17 17:25:18.174: D/DroidGap(534): DroidGap.loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/login.html?imeino=000000000000000&status=0)
12-17 17:25:18.244: D/DroidGap(534): DroidGap: url=file:///android_asset/www/login.html?imeino=000000000000000&status=0 baseUrl=file:///android_asset/www/
12-17 17:25:18.304: D/DroidGap(534): DroidGap.init()
12-17 17:25:18.354: I/dalvikvm(534): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-17 17:25:18.444: I/dalvikvm(534): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-17 17:25:18.494: D/PluginManager(534): init()
12-17 17:25:18.704: D/chromium(534): Unknown chromium error: -6
12-17 17:25:18.724: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(534): Ignore this event
12-17 17:25:18.864: I/dalvikvm(534): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-17 17:25:19.035: D/Cordova(534): DroidGap: GapViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-1 Description=A network error occurred. URL=file:///android_asset/www/login.html?imeino=000000000000000&status=0
12-17 17:25:19.044: I/dalvikvm(534): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-17 17:25:19.314: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(534): Ignore this event
12-17 17:25:19.364: I/dalvikvm(534): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-17 17:25:19.534: I/dalvikvm(534): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-17 17:25:19.644: D/dalvikvm(534): GC_CONCURRENT freed 87K, 2% free 13129K/13383K, paused 10ms+9ms
12-17 17:25:19.864: I/dalvikvm(534): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-17 17:25:19.984: I/dalvikvm(534): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not a manifest problem and is just a code one (for example: in newer versions of Android, your app will **crash** if you perform **Network operations in the UI thread**). Could you please add the **stack trace** of the error you're getting?

Comment: Is that the parameter is not working in the URL part in higher version how to fix this issue ??

Comment: Can anyone tell me the solution for this?

Comment: It is the parameter part that is not working in Android 4.X as that is an Android bug.

Comment: @simon  So what is the solution for this how should i fix this any alternative solution ?

Comment: Use localStorage to pass data between pages.